# Encrypt ESXI by veracrypt or luks. FDE

Tags: disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I need encrypt esxi host by veracrypt or luks. Any idea how to done it? Can I install linux/windows first, than ESXI, than fix bootloader, than encrypt FDE in windows/linux by veracrypt?
Best regards

Comment: a few links: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/inception-how-usable-are-nested-kvm-guests , https://serverfault.com/questions/28399/how-to-run-vmware-esx-or-esxi-in-a-virtual-machine (not written but correct IOMMU support is required, in all layers: board, bios, cpu), https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-8D7D09AC-8579-4A33-9449-8E8BA49A3003.html (this one requires vSphere not just ESXi)

Comment: Of course I'm not sure this question fits here: it's about considering Windows as host (since there's Veracrypt rather than LUKS, I doubt Linux would work here), and ESXi as guest which barely or not at all qualifies as an *nix.

Comment: ESXi is a hypervisor. You can't go underneath it with something like Veracrypt

Comment: @A.B Goal needed to achive here is to encrypt whole drive containing ESXi with 3th party tool. But on esxi you can't install veracrypt or dm-crypt. So I thought to install windows or linux next to ESXi on same drive, only for veracrypt and than encrypt whole drive from windows or linux level.

Comment: Do you mean that's for encrypting *offline* data before moving it?

Comment: No, I mean to encrypt whole drive containing esxi, system need to be bootable. In simple words: before ESXi start, I want computer ask to password. Without password only bootloader should be accessible rest must look like random.

Comment: Then I just tell what roaima wrote: you can't. Sorry No other idea about your question (which looks off-topic anyway).